# Delete every 7 days folders on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, lifecycle, bucket

How can I create a lifecycle rule that deletes every 7 days folders on the S3 Bucket? I already tried a rule that Expires current versions of objects but they are not being removed.

I checked these 2 options and didn't work:

- Expire current versions of objects
- Permanently delete non-current versions of objects

Maybe its better with a Lambda function? How can I do it?

[image: This is how i tried]

Comment: Amazon S3 doesn't really have folders. Are you okay to just delete the _objects_ with a particular Prefix, rather than the folders themselves? Also, do you really need to delete the objects every 7 days, or is it okay to delete the objects 7 days after they were created? This means that something created on Tuesday will be deleted next Tuesday, rather than everything being deleted on one particular day.

Comment: I need to delete all objectes after 7 days they were created.

Comment: Please Edit your question to provide details of how you configured the rule and what you checked to see whether it performed correctly.

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: What do you have in the bucket and what did you expect to happen?  Also, did you apply the rule to the entire bucket, or to a particular Prefix?

Comment: i applied the rule for the entire bucket, i expect that on the 8th date the voice call recordings created on day 0 are eliminated

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle rules run once a day at midnight Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). You might need to wait 24 hours after lifecycle rules

Comment: I waited 2 days and nothing happened, can you please share what i have to do and what options i have to check on the rule?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).